# How to make comparison an operation implemented by subclasses and Template pattern?

Tags: sorting, oop, design-patterns, programming-languages, gang-of-four

I started self learning design patterns from Design Patterns by Gang of Four

> Parameterized types give us a third way (in addition to class
>   inheritance and  object composition)  to compose behavior  in
>   object-oriented  systems. Many designs can be implemented using any of
>   these three techniques. **To parameterize a sorting routine by the
>   operation it uses to compare elements**, we could make the comparison
>
> 1. **an  operation  implemented  by  subclasses  (an  application  of  Template Method (325)),**
> 2. the responsibility of an object that's passed to the sorting routine (Strategy (315)), or
> 3. an argument  of a C++ template or Ada generic that specifies the name of the function to call to compare the elements.

I looked up the template pattern, but was still wondering how the first way "make the comparison an  operation  implemented  by  subclasses  (an  application  of  Template Method)" is done?

I'd appreciate some example(s) in whichever OO language: C++, C#,  Java, Python, ...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They're basically talking about something like this:

```
class Sorter {
  sort(Collection c) {
    ...
    if (isLessThan(a, b)) ...
    ...
  }

  abstract isLessThan();
}

class MyTypeSorter(Sorter) {
  isLessThan(a, b) {
    return a.member < b.member;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Which language did you write your example in? Or the closest language? (2) Which OO languages (or their standard libraries) provide template implementation of sorting? Java, C++, C#, Python, ...?

Comment: 1) It's psuedo code :) Sort of a mix between Java and Python, I guess. 2) Java, C#, and Python use Strategy; C++ uses a template parameter. I don't know of any language that uses the template function pattern for this, and I'll admit it sounds like a weird choice given the alternatives.